# Trying to add Links to my Dialog but getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, hyperlink, dialog

I want to add some links in my dialog, I have standard text but I also want to have some clickable links. But I get NPE error. I have tried many solutions but I always end up with nullpointerexception error;

here is my code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
        } else {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }

        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialogTitle) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        String msg = getResources().getString(R.string.dialogMessage);
        final SpannableString DialogMessage = new SpannableString(msg);
        Linkify.addLinks(DialogMessage, Linkify.ALL);
        builder.setMessage("Version " + AppVersion + "\n" + DialogMessage);
        builder.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.neutralText),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message))
        .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at com.sm.flashlightpro.MainFlashlightActivity.showInfoDialog(MainFlashlightActivity.java:213)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at com.sm.flashlightpro.MainFlashlightActivity$3.onClick(MainFlashlightActivity.java:124)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-06 16:36:36.774: E/AndroidRuntime(8521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The line 213 is:

```
((TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message))
```

Comment: Seems, dialog is null. Where your variable dialog is inited? Add more code.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot the most important part. -.- been looking to close to the problem and I didn't see the whole picture. But @ρяσѕρєя K answer fixed the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `dialog` is `null`.

Try it as using `Dialog` object which is return from `show()` method:

```
dialog=builder.show();
TextView textView=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

Comment: This has fixed the NPE error. I can't believe I missed the most important part lol. But, I still can't click on links. But that's different problem. Now that I was able to get text variable it should be easy. Thanks. Will accept answer in 3 minutes

Comment: @SlimC.: probably need to set `android:linksClickable="false"` attribute for TextView

Comment: Well it's not a custom dialog but I will look into documentation for that. It should be easy now that I have textView. :D

Comment: Maybe something about foucs

Answer (score 0):

Where is your dialog from?

`((TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message))`

Comment: Yeah I forgot  the most important part lol. It never occurred to me that dialog was not initialized.